# Sails Waterline Query Null Value

Tags: sql-server, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to query null values from my database. What is the correct syntax?

I am using the sails SQL Server waterline adapter.

I have tried:

```
?ChoiceItem=isNull
?ChoiceItem=Null
?ChoiceItem="null"
```

I feel pretty sure it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Waterline query language](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md)

```
?where={"ChoiceItem":null}
```

I think this should work fine.